# using flexible array member with mmap

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault, mmap, flexible-array-member

I'm having trouble accessing a global struct pointer that I'm initalizing with mmap. Attempting to access members of the struct in functions outside of the one it is declared in throw segfaults.

the struct:

```
typedef struct foo {
  uint32_t size;
  bar_t array[0];
} foo_t;
```

the initialization:

```
foo_t* foo; // global

static void* init_function(...) {
  fd = open(filename, O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, 0644);
  write(...);
  lseek(...);
  write(...);
  foo = mmap(0, BIG_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
  close(fd);
  foo->size = 0;
}
```

what causes the segfault:

```
static int another_function(...) {
  if (foo->size == 0) {...} //foo->size causes it
}
```

BIG_SIZE is a defined value that should be adequately large for my needs.

Any ways, I apologize for the (...)s, but this is where the issues are showing up. I've looked into mmap docs and variable length methods with no luck. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I edited your question to use the correct vocabluary. VLA are something different. Also, you shouldn't have `[0]` in the declaration, but just `[]`, this is how C as of C99 requests it.

Comment: oh, it does have [0] in the actual struct, I just copied it down wrong.

Comment: Other minor points: you shouldn't use `_t` names, these are reserved by POSIX, just  `foo` also for the type name would suffice. (And using a name such as `foo` that is also a tag name of a `struct` is generally not a good idea.) Then your function is supposed to return a `void*` but doesn't return anything.

Comment: Do you check for errors from `mmap(2)`? At the very least, the file needs to be open for reading if you want to read from the mapping. (You can't use `O_WRONLY`.)

Comment: the _t names were given as a part of the skeleton code I'm working off of (that I have truncated somewhat), and foo and bar are used as placeholders here for the actual struct names in my code. basically: I have skeleton code that I'm working off of and I only copied over a small part of it and modified the naming of the others. also the function does return something, I just only copied over 5/20 of the lines as the others are irrelevant to this question.

Comment: As @Ulfalizer  says -- check for errors from `mmap()` -- man page says: ERRORS
     mmap() will fail if:

     [EACCES]           The flag PROT_READ was specified as part of the prot
                        parameter and fd was not open for reading.  ...

Answer (score 0):

You don't show us everything, but it seems that you just assign your global variable, but that you don't initialize the contents of the mapped region. You should at least give it a
`foo->size = 0` somewhere, if the file is newly created, or alternatively you should use `ftruncate` instead of your `fseek write` sequence to warrant that the blocks (including `size`) are `0` filled.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check if mmap really succeeded:

foo = mmap(...);

if ( MAP_FAILED == foo )
{
   //no memory for me...
}

And if I remember correctly, the file must be at least `BIG_SIZE` long, otherwise `mmap` will fail - but I may be wrong on that part...